# How to create a Approval Workflow using Entity Framework

Tags: .net

my table structure is Id(PrimaryKey),Workflowid,Nextid,Fileid(ForeignKey)
if file is created means workflowid should be 1 and nextid should be2,
file is verified means workflowid should be 2 and nextid should be 3but the Primarykey should be Same Upto the File reaches to the Approvred Status.

Comment: What exactly is your question and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.